# UITableView with Navigation within UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on an app that has a UITableView and then when you click on an element it takes you to a sub table view. I have written that functionality, but I would like the sub table view to have a navigation controller, so the user can click to return to the top UITableView. How do I implement a navigation controller in a sub UITableView?

On an element click do I send the view to the sub UITableView or to the navigation controller.

Answer (score 2):

For implementing that you would need to set your top table view as root to NavigationController then your sub table view with have navigation look n feel. Code is as below :-

```
TopTableViewController *topTable = [[TopTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *tableViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:topTable];
```

Now when you push from top table view to sub table view then you will have navigation bar also in sub table view.

Comment: What file does this go into? Currently Im in the TopTableViewController "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"

Comment: in aapDelegate.m ( applicationDidFinishLaunch method) you could write this so root controller will have navigation and so will sub view's will have.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can implement the navigation controller upon calling the sub.
code goes something like this:

```
UITableViewController *myTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
UINavigationController *tableViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myTableViewController];
```

what you should do is create a navigation controller and set the table view controller as its root